# How to use transaction in oracle database from java back end?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, transactions

I have to insert some information to my oracle database. Some of them are complex (array of arrays), so I can't pass them to a PL/SQL function. All the data can't be inserted using one query, and I have to insert data to multiple tables too. But if insertion fails once for a table, the whole insertion process should be rolled back. So I need to use transaction.

I am using java code and `PreparedStatement`, `ResultSet`, `CallableStatement` and other related things to perform database operations from my java back end. How can I define and use transactions from this java back end? Basically I am using Spring MVC.

N.B. No `Hibernate` related solution please.

Comment: Please read [JDBC(TM) Database Access Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), especially this chapter: [Using Transactions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Connection.setAutoComit(false)` just after obtaining the `Connection` instance.

This will make your connection a non auto-commit transaction.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-

Comment: Then how will I commit after a successful transaction from my java code?

Comment: `Connection.close()` will commit, thrown exception will rollback.

Comment: Oh, and there are `Connection.commit()` and `Connection.rollback()` methods, too...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using java 8 see oracle [full explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html)

Comment: I am using Java 8. This should work with Java 8, right?

Comment: Yes. This is more general explanation